# SQL view using double joins between tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create a view using a double join between tables.

I'm working on some travel software, managing holiday bookings. The different items a person pays for can be in different currencies.

I've a table of bookings, and a table of currencies.

There are many different items a person can pay for, all stored in different tables. I've created a view showing the total owed per payment Item type.

e.g. owed for Transfers:

```
BookingID  CurrencyID  TotalTransfersPrice
1          1           340.00
2          1           120.00
2          2           100.00
```

e.g. owed for Extras:

```
BookingID  CurrencyID  TotalExtrasPrice
1          1           200.00
1          2           440.00
2          1           310.00
```

All is good so far.

What I'd like to do is to create a master view that brings this all together:

```
BookingID  CurrencyID  TotalExtrasPrice  TotalTransfersPrice
1          1           200.00            340.00
1          2           440.00            NULL
2          1           310.00            120.00
2          2           NULL              100.00
```

I can't figure out how to make the above. I've been experimenting with double joins, as I'm guessing I need to do joins both for the BookingID and the CurrencyID?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Phil.

Comment: You should always specify which DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...) you are using. It might be that the optimal solution depends on your DBMS.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? It is better to accept one of the answers below if helps..

Comment: I'm using sql server, sorry I missed that out. The answer from Luis LL below worked. Thanks very much everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SQL Server`

This query allows each {`BookingId`, `CurrencyId`} have more than one row in the `Transfer` and `Extras` tables.

since you stated

> I've created a view showing the total owed per payment Item type.

I'm accumulating them by BookinID and CurrencyID

```
 SELECT ISNULL(transfers.BookingId, extras.BookingId) AS BookingId,  
       ISNULL(transfers.CurrencyId, extras.CurrencyId) AS CurrencyId,
       SUM(TotalExtrasPrice) AS TotalExtrasPrice,
       SUM(t.TotalTransfersPrice) AS TotalTransfersPrice
FROM transfers
FULL OUTER JOIN extras ON transfers.BookingId = extras.BookingId and transfers.CurrencyId = extras.CurrencyId
GROUP BY ISNULL(transfers.BookingId, extras.BookingId),ISNULL(transfers.CurrencyId, extras.CurrencyId)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the `full outer join` in joining the two tables: **Transfers** & **Extras**. Assuming you are using MySQL platform, the sql query can be:

```
SELECT t.BookingId,t.CurrencyId,e.TotalExtrasPrice,t.TotalTransfersPrice
FROM transfers as t FULL OUTER JOIN extras as e
ON t.BookingId = e.BookingId AND t.CurrencyId = e.CurrencyId;
```

Answer (score 0):

use joins

```
select t.BookingId,t.CurrencyId,e.TotalExtrasPrice,t.TotalTransfersPrice
from transfers as t
join extras as e
on t.BookingId = e.BookingId and t.CurrencyId = e.CurrencyId
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cover the case where a combination of BookingID and CurrencyID only exist in either Transfers or Extras and you still want to include them in the result (rather than finding the intersect) this query will do that:

```
SELECT IDs.BookingId, IDs.CurrencyID, e.TotalExtrasPrice,t.TotalTransfersPrice 
FROM (
  SELECT BookingId,CurrencyId FROM transfers 
  UNION
  SELECT BookingId,CurrencyId FROM extras 
) IDs 
LEFT JOIN transfers t ON IDs.BookingId=t.BookingId AND IDs.CurrencyID=t.CurrencyID
LEFT JOIN extras e ON IDs.BookingId=e.BookingId AND IDs.CurrencyID=e.CurrencyID
```

This query will produce a result identical to your example.

Answer (score 0):

This works. All you need is a simple *full outer join*.

```
SELECT "BookingID", "CurrencyID",
       ext."TotalExtrasPrice", trans."TotalTransfersPrice"
FROM Transfers trans FULL OUTER JOIN Extras ext
USING ("BookingID", "CurrencyID");
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03f44f/10)** demo using *Oracle*.